# How to show all fields of a document in view?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have to list all the fields present inside a document in Firebase Firestore in my Android app. How to implement it?

For example in the attached screenshot, I have to show all the fields in the document "hIYsLb7YW0dGe5b1mmpiGrEbYJ03" in my app.

[image: Screenshot of Document]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to display the name of all the fields inside your "hIYsLb7YW0dGe5b1mmpiGrEbYJ03", please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference docId = rootRef.collection("UsersLogDetail").document("hIYsLb7YW0dGe5b1mmpiGrEbYJ03");
docId.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    fieldNames.add(entry.getKey());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, fieldNames.toString());
                //Do what you need to do with your services List of property names
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, you need to read the content of the entire document. Please note that DocumentSnapshot's [getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getData()) method, returns a Map<String, Object> that can be simply iterated like any other Map in Java.

The result in the logcat will be:

```
[07-04-21 17:45:26, 07-04-21 17:45:46 ... 07-04-21 17:46:55]
```